# Hibernate get column property

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm interested in getting the "Description" property of a table column. Is it possible to do via Hibernate? I'm using Sql Server 2008.

Edit: I'm trying to map the column description found in information_schema to the corresponding column (JPA column entity)

Comment: By *"description"* property, you probably mean table meta-data, right? i.e. you'd like to query the `sys` schema or `information_schema`?

Comment: You are right. I'm trying to access table meta-data. I've edited my question to hopefully make it clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the simplest solution would be mapping of `informatio_schema` in way that will provide the information for columns. If you are using annotations you easily can access to information like `Table name` and `Column name`, that can be used in `Criteria` to fetch the description.

This is probably re-coding some available feature and non platform depend. But if you will not succeed in research is always some solution.